# AJAX or more specific MooTools Request.JSON error types?

Tags: ajax, mootools

I'm trying to get myself an overview about all the errors that can occur on Request.JSON().
I've googled for a while but there seems not to be any overview about them all.
What I've figured out was that the 404 error occures if no such file is available to request on.

Does anyone have an idea where to find them? I think it has not to be specific mootools errors, what I'm looking for are the AJAX errors itself.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Well, Ajax itself has no 'error codes'. Ajax is simply an asynchronous request you are making to a server without refreshing a page.

Things that can go wrong are the same things that can go wrong on a normal request. These are for instance the http status codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Some frameworks implement some extra error codes or change some of them. Most frameworks/libs (like Mootools) have a usefull onFailure() function that passes in the xhr object used dor the request.

The 'error' code is thus noet an 'ajax' code but a http code.